# WordPress - Pull In HomePage Title To Any Other Page For Breadcrumb

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs

I have set up a breadcrumb on my site and now due to wanting to integrate WPML into the site, I can no longer leave the homepage breadcrumb with a hard coded name.

Could anyone tell me how I can pull in the title from the front / static page (home page)?

I have the code below:

```
echo '<li><a href="'. get_settings('home') .'">Home</a> > </li>';
```

but am not able to find anything in the documentation that explains how to do this.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean home page or front page?  Either way, it will be a variation of `get_options`.

Check the codex.

Get the Front Page ID: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option#Parameters

Get a page title by ID: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title

**Front Page**

```
echo '<li><a href="'. get_settings('home') .'">Home</a>'.get_the_title(get_option('page_on_front')).'</li>';
```

**Blog Page**

```
echo '<li><a href="'. get_settings('home') .'">Home</a>'.get_the_title(get_option('page_for_posts')).'</li>';
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  That works perfectly!